# MySQL: JOIN table B but return table A if no matches in table B

Tags: mysql, sql

This is an abstraction of a problem I have. I have two tables:

```
id  name
--  ------
1   Frank
2   Tom

id  bar  drink
--  ---  -----
1    5   water
1    5   beer
1    6   wine
2    5   milk
```

I want to select id 1, bar 5 and get Frank and all his drinks at the bar 5.

```
id: 1, name: Frank, bar: 5, drink: water
id: 1, name: Frank, bar: 5, drink: beer
id: 1, name: Frank, bar: 5, drink: wine
```

But when I select id 1 and bar 9 I want to get Frank with no drinks.

```
id: 1, name: Frank
```

I tried with left join union right join, but I always end up getting unwanted drinks in other bars. I am trying to do this query with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `left join` query with careful filtering:

```
select t1.*, t2.bar, t2.drink
from t1 left join 
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t2.bar = 9
where t1.name = 'Frank';
```

The `left join` ensures that all rows in the first table are in the output.  The `where` then filters these rows to get the name that you want.  Key to this is the `on` clause with the condition on the second table.  If there is a match, you will get the matching rows in the second table.  Otherwise, you will get a row with `NULL` values in the `t2` columns.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the explanation. ..and t2.bar = 9 after on was my missing part